# npm-scripts running git - user credentials not set

Tags: git, npm

I have a problem using the [npm-scripts option](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script). If I run git via the run option it is not using my user credentials. I can see it by simply checking my git config settings running on the shell and via the run script option. Any ideas how to use my user settings / credentials when running via npm? Thanks!

```
package.json
...
"scripts": {
  "git": "git config -l"
},
...

shell
$git config -l
$npm run git
```

Comment: I get identical output from running `git config -l` on the shell and via a script. What OS are you using? What shell are you using? What is the output of `echo $SHELL`? (assuming you're on *nix)

Comment: I'm on Win7 & Git Bash.

Comment: Have a look at `git config --list --show-origin` and make sure, the credentials are set and not overwritten in a local configuration.

Comment: Running `git config --list --show-origin` via npm misses all the user properties which are fetched from my user folder running the command on the git bash. No local user settings are used in the project folder.

Comment: @LordMidi That explains it. When you work on the shell, you use git bash. When you run an npm script, you are using `cmd.exe`. I can't tell you how to work around this, but you should update your question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RyanZim - the problem is caused by my system settings and using Windows & Git Bash.

The home folder settings on the Git Bash & `cmd.exe` differ. NPM is using `cmd.exe`, so my `.ssh` folder cannot be found as it does on the Git Bash.

Solution: clone the .ssh folder to both home folders or fix the system settings to have ONE home folder for Git Bash & `cmd.exe`.

Compare your setting with `ENV | grep 'HOME'` (Git Bash) and `SET` (`cmd.exe`).